# How to use Webpack loaders in Vite?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vite

I'm using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev). I want to use [lit-scss-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-scss-loader) or any loader in my Vite app. I found that SASS and JSX are supported by default in Vite. But I'm not able to find any documentation about custom loaders in Vite website.

Comment: You can't use webpack loaders in vite, you need to use vite plugins instead. You can however try to convert a webpack loader to a vite plugin, if the loader is pretty simple it's doable, if you have the time to do it. It's still js so perhaps a good chunk of the code still apply to vite, however all the api calls will be different, so there will be some rewriting.

Comment: @Lk77 so is there any way to copy that loader source code and create a Vite native loader or something like that?

Comment: Yes you can do that, however depending on the loader you want to copy over to vite, and how well that loader is made, that can be easy, or hard or even impossible

Comment: Seen as Vite uses the rollup plugin architecture, maybe -> https://github.com/GiG/rollup-plugin-webpack-loader  might help, not been updated for 4 years, but that might not be an issue if it just works..

Answer (score 0):

By default without plugins, you can just load sass files using `?inline` query suffix.

```js
import { LitElement, html, unsafeCSS } from 'lit';
import styles from './my-element.scss?inline';

export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static styles = unsafeCSS(styles);
  ...
```

[Example](https://github.com/e111077/vite-lit-element-ts-sass/tree/master) from Elliott Marquez who is on the lit team.

You can also use [a small plugin I created](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mordech/vite-lit-loader) that works on the same principle but saves you wrapping it in `unsafeCSS()` for every import.

```js
import styles from './my-element.scss?lit';

export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static styles = styles;
  ...
```

I hope that helps!